# Save activity instance on fragment introduce memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I save the activity instance to use it inside the fragment like this, but does it introduce memory leaks?

```
@Override public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = (MainDrawerActivity) activity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Leak Canary to find out. I just found out that it does. Thinking of an alternative to solve the issue.

Comment: I´m usign getActivity() everytime I need it

Comment: @kevin-tan Did you know any alternative to this ?